# Training a multilayer perceptron to play cards

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm writing a multilayer perceptron neural network for playing two-player card games. I'd like to know if there is a better way to optimize weights than testing neural nets with randomly regenerated weights against each other.

Here's the way I implemented the neural net.

- The neurons in the first layer output field values representing states of cards in the deck. For each of these neurons there is an array of constant weights. For example, if the card is in AI's hand, the neuron outputs field equal to the first weight in the array, if the card is on the table - the second, and so forth. These constant input weights need to be optimized in the training process.
- Next, there are several hidden layers of neurons. The topology is fixed. All neurons in the preceding layer are connected to every neuron in the following layer. The connections' weights need to be optimized.
- The last layer of neurons represents player's actions. These correspond to card that can be played, plus a couple non-card-specific actions, like take cards from the table, or end turn. The largest output field value corresponding to a legal action determines the action to play.

There is a caveat. I want the neural net to find the optimum strategy, so I cannot train it on individual turns. Rather, I have to let it play until it wins or looses, and that's approximately 50 turns.
I'm wondering what is the best approach to training in this scenario, where one does not know the proper response for every turn, but only know if the problem was solved correctly after multiple NN evaluations, i.e. it won the game.

For now, I've only thought of a simple evolutionary approach, in which a group of randomly generated NNs play against each other multiple times, and a few most successful ones remain for the next round, where the NNs which didn't pass are replaced by other random ones. The problem I see is that in this approach it's going to take a long time for the weights to start converging. But since the fraction of wins is a function of many weights (I'm expecting to need several hundreds to properly model the problem) which have highly non-linear effect on the NN output, I don't see how I could use a function minimization technique.

Does anyone know if this weight optimization problem would lend itself better to anything other then the a Monte Carlo technique?

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on what your card game is. In general, I think this statement of yours is false:

> There is a caveat. I want the neural net to find the optimum strategy, so I cannot train it on individual turns.

It should be possible to find a way to train your network on individual turns. For example, if both players can make the same exact set of moves at each turn, you can train the loser network according to what the winner did at each of the turns. Admittedly, this might not be the case for most card games, where the set of moves at a given turn is usually determined by the cards each player is holding.

If you're playing something like poker, look at [this](http://mattmazur.com/2009/10/13/experimenting-with-a-neural-network-based-poker-bot/). The idea there is to train your network based on the history of a player you consider good enough to learn from. For example, if you have a lot of data about your favorite (poker) player's games, you can train a neural network to learn their moves. Then, at each turn of a new game, do what the neural network tells you to do given its previous training and the data you have available up to that turn: what cards you're holding, what cards are on the table, what cards you know your opponents to be holding etc.

You could also consider [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning), which can make use of neural nets, but is based on a different idea. This might help you deal with your "cannot train on individual turns" problem, without needing training data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I understand that it may be possible to train turn by turn with some games, and I've read that people do that for poker. But I don't think this can be done for the games of interest to me. Think gin rummy for example. Also, training turn by turn would usually require comparison to a database of somebody else's plays, buy I want my neural net to find its own strategy rather then emulate somebody. On of the things I want to find out is whether the NN can learn to play well enough that it can be used to learn something about strategy. I'll take a look at your link.